A representation formula of solution to the linearized Euler equation
It's in the paper  https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.21672.
We consider the linearized Euler equation around the shear flow $(u(y),0),$ in a finite channel $\{(x,y):x\in\mathbb{T},y\in [0,1]\}$
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\partial_t w+\mathcal{L}w=0
\end{equation}
with initial data $w|_{t=0}=w_0(x,y),$ where $\mathcal{L}=u(y)\partial_x+u^{''}(y)\partial_x(-\Delta)^{-1}$ and $u(y)$ is monotonic in $[0,1].$
In terms of stream function $\psi,$ namely $-\Delta\psi=w$, the linearized Euler equation is
$$
\partial_t\Delta\psi+u(y)\partial_x\Delta\psi-u^{''}(y)\partial_x\psi=0,
$$
taking the Fourier transform in x, we get
$$
-\frac{1}{i\alpha}\partial_t\hat{\psi}=\mathcal{R}_{\alpha}\hat{\psi},
$$
where $\mathcal{R}_{\alpha}\hat{\psi}=-(\partial_y^2-\alpha^2)^{-1}\big(u^{''}(y)-u(y)(\partial_y^2-\alpha^2)\big)\hat{\psi}.$
The authors said in the paper that if $\mathcal{L}$ has no embedding eigenvalues and $P_{\mathcal{L}}w_0,$then
$$
\hat{\psi}(t,\alpha,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{u(0)}^{u(1)}e^{-i\alpha tc}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\big((c-i\epsilon-\mathcal{R}_{\alpha})^{-1}-(c-i\epsilon-\mathcal{R}_{\alpha})^{-1}\big)\hat{\psi}(0,\alpha,y)dc.
$$
I have the following questions:
(1) Why do we have to assume that $\mathcal{L}$ has no embedding eigenvalues and $P_{\mathcal{L}}w_0=0$?
(2)How can we get the representation formula of $\hat{\psi}$ in the above form?
My attempt:
We get thanks to Dunford's formula
$$
\hat{\psi}(t,\alpha,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\Omega}e^{-i\alpha tc}(c-\mathcal{R}_{\alpha})^{-1}\hat{\psi}(0,\alpha,y)dc
$$
where $\Omega$ is a simple connected domain containing the spectrum of $\mathcal{R}_{\alpha}.$
But I do not know how to get the spectrum of $\mathcal{R}_{\alpha}$ precisely and I do not know how to go from this formula to the one in the paper.
